# How do I create particles in a mob with an effect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make when I shoot an enemy with a tipped_arrow with the effect Fire Resistance, this active a particle in them.

I make this command that actually work but not how I would like...

```
/testfor @e[type=Spider] {ActiveEffects:[{Id:12b}]}
```

and next with a comparator, I use this command for active the particles...

```
/execute @e[type=Spider] ~ ~ ~  /particle flame ~ ~1 ~ 1.5 1 1.5 0 3 normal @e
```

The problem is that this active the particle in all spiders and not in the specific spider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use a scoreboard tag. The scoreboard command, like testfor, can search for entities with partial nbt matches, but can also mark them for other commands.

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=spider] add SpiderMark {ActiveEffects:[{Id:12b}]}
```

If you use this all spider's with fire resistance will receive the "SpiderMark" tag. Then you can add the `tag=SpiderMark` to the entity selector in the particle command to only play the particle command off spider's with fire resistance.

```
/execute @e[type=spider,tag=SpiderMark] ~ ~ ~ particle flame ~ ~1 ~ 1.5 1 1.5 0 3 normal @a
```